# Is there a way to prevent Remote Desktop from locking?

Tags: c#

I am using `AxMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting` in a c# application to connect to a remote server. Now I want to prevent the remote desktop from locking.

Is there any way through which I can achieve this?

EDIT:

In my system, to prevent it from locking (since I can't change settings) I use MouseJiggle application which basically repeatedly sends mouse movement to the system

```
public static class Jiggler
{

  internal const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
  internal const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 1;

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

  public static void Jiggle(int dx, int dy)
  {
    if (Jiggler.SendInput(1U, ref new INPUT()
    {
      TYPE = 0,
      dx = dx,
      dy = dy,
      mouseData = 0,
      dwFlags = 1,
      time = 0,
      dwExtraInfo = (IntPtr) 0
    }, 28) != 1U)

      throw new Win32Exception();
  }
}
```

Can I send these mouse movements to the Remote server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/269438/how-to-stop-remote-desktop-from-closing-my-session-due-to-inactivity

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the comment but unfortunately, I can't edit any settings on the remote server.

I was looking more to what I can add in my c# code that would achieve this, like is there any property/method of  `AxMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting`  that can help me send some keys to server or something like that?